# Equivalent of 'git rebase --skip' for 'hg rebase'

Tags: mercurial

I'm doing a Mercurial rebase (induced by `hg histedit`) and I reach a conflict where I realize, actually, I should have dropped this patch. In git, I would have just done `git rebase --skip`. Is there an equivalent in Mercurial?

Answer (score 3):

If you realize you should have dropped it, then the safe bet would be to do `hg histedit --abort`, then redo `hg histedit` and select `drop` for that changeset.

The only downside is losing progress on any other changeset conflicts already resolved in the same operation. To avoid that, there's `hg histedit --edit-plan` that allows changing the changeset to `drop`, and then use `hg histedit --continue`. But the current conflict still has to be resolved first, so for example `hg resolve --all --mark` could be done first. But I think this depends on the details of the current situation and gets much more complex and risky, and in most cases is probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, the point is that you already did a bunch of work and don't want to drop it. :/